# How to undo xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1.?

Tags: macos, dropbox

Is there any command to undo `xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1.` on MacOS to start syncing the folder back to dropbox?

**Update**: I found the solution, but not sure if it is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
xattr -d com.dropbox.ignored <path-to-file>
```

This way, you make sure only to delete the flag in question not any other flags.

Answer (score 1):

This method removes all the extended attributes for the file/folder

```
xattr -c <absolute-path-to-file>
```

Reference: https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html